# Converting between Cartesian and polar coordinates when only one of each is known.

Tags: physics, polar-coordinates

Cartesian coordinates of a point are given by **(7, y)**, and its polar coordinates are given by **(r, 11pi/6)**. Find **y** and **r**. Assume **r** is equal to or greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Draw a picture: You should show the $\frac{11\pi}{6}$ ray and see where it intersects the vertical line $x=7$.

Comment: That *does* look like it would work. But is there any way to solve the problem without using graphs?

Comment: You could use: $\frac{y}{7}=\tan\frac{11\pi}{6}$, allowing you to find $y$, and then $r^2=7^2+y^2$ to find $r$ (which is to take a positive value).